# how can i set confirmation value for jQuery popup

Tags: jquery, css

my html

`<a href="/cart/?empty_cart=yes" class="emptybutton" title="Empty Bag">Empty cart</a>`

i tried to add popup confirmation for .emptybutton in jQuery but ( ok or cancel ) have the same value , if i click cancel it won't abort

[image]

this is the jQuery i used

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.emptybutton').click(function() {
   if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load(url);
    }
  });
});
```

i dont know were is my problem

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do like this. You should prevent the a button click when you click `cancel` button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.emptybutton').click(function(e) {
   if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load(url);
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```